# Partial update of previously cached responses

Tags: php, rest, caching, cache-control

I´m building a REST API in php from scratch, got it working, and now, I want to handle cache related to headers so clientes don´t have to request again and again resources they already have.

Every entity in the rest service is linked to a database table, and the approach I´m using is a created/updated field on every table, so I can serve a "Last-modified" header on every resource request.

Only to make it clear how do I handle the requests, this is the piece of code that generates the response, and where I plan to add the "Last modified" header

```
switch( strtolower($requestMethod) ){
...
case "get":{
    if ($resourceId){
        $this->resource = $resourceType::byId($resourceId);
        if ( !$this->resource ){
            $this->responseCode = 404;
        }
        else{
            $this->responseBody = json_encode($this->resource); 
            $this->responseCode = 200;
            $this->responseHeaders["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
        }   
    }
    else{
        $this->responseBody = json_encode($resourceType::find($this->requestData));
        $this->responseCode = 200;
        $this->responseHeaders["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    }
}
break;
...
}
```

To make it clearer, with the following request /api/products/1 $resourceType would by products and $resourceId would be 1.

Now, for caching, if $resourceId is present I will simply add a "Last-modified" header with its last updated timestamp.

In case there is no $resourceId, I would query for the highest updated timestamp in the collection and put it as the last modified header.

This last point is where I have the problem. Let´s say that I have 20000 products in my database, and update the price of a single one; that would mean that a request to api/products after the update would have to fetch again the 20000 items, although only 1 byte of data has been modified, and I want to know if there is a way to tell the browser that it should fetch only one record and update its cache.

It´s my first REST service made from scratch, so, any advice on the piece of code I posted is welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know if there is a way to tell the browser that it should fetch only one record and update its cache.

No, not when you serve a single resource with all records.

The browser cache is happy to manage the separate expiry times for the separate products, but there's no general mechanism for sending a diff back to a browser.

Solutions have been proposed (e.g., [`Vary: ETag`](https://intertwingly.net/blog/2004/09/11/Vary-ETag)) as essentially the same problem turns up when polling for Atom feeds, but they require a client that's aware of these techniques.

Either reduce the size of your main resource, or accept that it's going to be served on every change.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have to think an alternative approach then, because a single page can contain 10M of information, and it´s not acceptable a new load on every request; maybe fetch by page could ease this one a bit?

Comment: Yes; splitting by page so only some resources are invalidated would be a good way to allow more cache reuse.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a server side cache. Its easier to manage. You can create a php database table and store the api response in the table. You can also use a memcache server for caching the response of your api

Comment: Sorry but I don´t see how would that help with the question I asked. The caching stuff is already done, and works well, also I can easily identify those records that were updated, what I cannot do yet is a partial update in the client cache, and don´t even know if is possible.